# Send notifications to user in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to build a notification system in my Android app where I can send a notification to someone upon an event. For example, my app is about a social system where it uses Firestore database (Firebase) to save its users (which means I have a 'users' collection in there), and I have an 'Add as Friend' feature.

Everything works just fine, but I would like to add a feature where when `user1` adds `user2` as a friend, I would like to send `user2` a notification about that.

 I have searched in google and saw this post: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-push-notification-in-android-using-firebase-cloud-messaging/

Now, from what I understand, this wouldn't help me much cause it only sends the notification from FCM by me (and not to a specific user).

The problem is, I don't really know what to search for (or what to type in google) in order to find what I'm looking for.

Some ideas I thought:

- to make a collection in firestore called 'Notifications' where it holds usernames as documentIDs
- when `user1` sends a friend request to `user2`, I would add data (like title/message) to 'Notifications/user2/'

But I'm kind of stuck here, I would like to know ideas or if you guys have threads on how do I implement this, I really don't know what should I look for.

Thank you very much and sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase creates a userID for every user and a usertoken which is a temporary identifier for the device which is connected to this userID. You need to save the usertoken when there is a new one being created in a database(firestore) along with the user with whom you identify this person.

When someone adds this person as a friend you can add a notification in the database that there is a request from person1 to person2.
This change in the database can trigger a cloud function that reacts to changes in the database.

The triggered cloud function sends an FCM to the person which is being added as a friend. This FCM can either be a pure notification or you send data and let your app handle how this data is being handled(saved in a local database or displayed as a custom notification).

Keywords are: FCM, Notification, Firestore, cloud functions, and firebase token

Edit (Answer to 1. comment): Firebase userID and usertoken are created on the device. In the tutorial you implement FCM(I didn't read it complete) and a class called FirebaseMessagingService, from which you can inherit. This class is called, when a message is sent to the device and contains a method called onNewToken. This message is called, when the Firebase Server creates a token for your device and sends it to the device. In this method you might want to send the new token to your database and save it as an identifier for the user of this device. The Tokens are used by firebase to identify devices, to which messages are being sent(You can read about FCM in detail)

Cloud functions are something you can deploy along your firebase project, which get triggered when an event occurs. For example a http call, or a specific change in your database. Cloud functions are written in JS and need to be deployed for your firebase project. (Cloud functions are not for free and you need to pay for each call, but you have some thousand uses for free each month.)

You send a FCM to a specific person by creating a firebase message which is directed to a specific token, tokens or user groups. To identify the person to which you want to send a message you need to have the token for this user, that is why you are saving the tokens from the 1. part in your database and always update the token, when the token changes on the device.

Keep in mind, that a user might use multiple devices. You should have an identifier for you, such as username and along this username you save multiple firebaseIds and Firebase tokens. A single FCM can be directed to up to 100 tokens.

Comment: Please bear with me, some questions I don't really understand:
(1) how do firebase create userID and userToken, I mean the 'users' collection is something I declared and not a built up thing in firebase, isn't it just bunch of strings for firebase ? I could call the collection 'abc' and the firebase wouldn't know what is it used for (Unless I really didn't understand that point)
(2) That cloud function is built-in or should I implement it ? 
(3) How can I send the FCM to one person ? This doesn't seem to be an option as I saw in the post
Thanks for replying, really appreciate it

Comment: @TannousTannous updated my answer. (I saw in your profile, that you already asked something about cloud functions a year ago, so I guess you know what they are about)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, this sure explains a lot. Just some more things:
(1) Line 4 in the edited answer, after 'onNewToken', you meant 'This method' right (as in onNewToken method)?
(2) is there a way to this using something else than cloud functions?
(3) I can save the Tokens inside the 'users' collection in firestore right ?
(4) what happens if I logout and another user logs in from my device ?

Comment: (1) no, this class contains 2 methods. onNewToken() which is called when you receive a new token and onMessageReceived() which is called when your device receives a message from firebase. (2) You can use a separate server which sends the FCM, never send tokens from an user to another user directly, this is a big security problem. (3) Yes, you should make sure that you save the token to the right person. (4) update your database on login and logout (remove or add the token)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, you made everything clear to me, I appreciate it <3